# How to store the thread reference which is used in method.invoke() in java

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a java class which has implemented `runnable`. In the run method, I have wrote code that invokes a method call `MyClass.MyMethod()` using `.invoke()` java reflection.

At same time in another class and in another thread, I need to check if the there is currently execude `MyClass.MyMethod()` (invoked by the reflection) and if its execution time is exceeding **1 hour**. If so, it needs to get the thread of `method.invoke()` and kill the method.

**My question:** How can I get and kill the thread from which I have called  `method.invoke()` to execute `MyClass.MyMethod()`.

```
//Class which is invoke the custom method MyClass.MyMethod()
public class MyBGPThread implements runnable {
    public void run() {
        object.getClass()
              .getMethod(methodName, objectTypeArray)
              .invoke(object, objectArray);
    }
}

// Another class running in a different thread
// From here I'm trying to access and kill the thread that executes MyClass.MyMethod()
public class MyClass {
    public void MyMethod() {
        //what to put here?
    }
}
```

**Note:** There may be multiple instance of this same `MyClass.MyMethod()` is invoked. Need to get the individual thread of each invocation.

Comment: Do you ask how to _get_ the current thread or how to _store_ the reference?

Comment: How to store the reference so that i can get the those thread reference in another class ?

Comment: Well, that would work the same as with any other reference you pass around: you pass in some repository object you register that reference to, use mechanism that supports lookups such as CDI or JNDI to get such a repository or use a static reference to such a repo (the least preferrable option).